# compute sum of two array in a array and print out the result array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have two pointer arrays for example `ptr1` and `ptr2`, a size of 10 for each, and init random variable for every element for both. I want to compute and init two elements of ptr1 and ptr2 for each element of another array called `ptr3`. But when I print `ptr3` out. It is not changed at all.

here is my code:

```
void evaluateArr(int* ptr1, int* ptr2, double* ptr3, int n) {
    // ptr3 = new double[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (ptr1[i] > ptr2[i]) {
            ptr3[i] = (double)(*(ptr1 + i) * 60 / 100);
            ptr3[i] += (double)(ptr2[i] * 40 / 100);
        } else {
            ptr3[i] = (double)(*(ptr2 + i) * 60 / 100);
            ptr3[i] += (double)(ptr1[i] * 40 / 100);
        }
    }
}

void printResult(double* ptr3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", *(ptr3 + i));
    }
}

int main() {

    int ptr1[10], ptr2[10];
    double ptr3[10];
    // init for arr1 and arr2
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ptr1[i] = (rand() % 100);
        ptr2[i] = (rand() % 100);
    }
    // it prints out 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    evaluateArr(ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, 10);
    printResult(ptr3);
}
```

Comment: Use `%f` for double, not `%d`.

Comment: Also, all your calculations are doing integer operations. So you will not get a true double result. Change to `*(ptr1 + i) * 60.0 / 100`. That is, casting the final result to `double` is too late. Make one of the numbers `double ` instead.

Comment: I would write `ptr3[i] = (double)(*(ptr1 + i) * 60 / 100);  ptr3[i] += (double)(ptr2[i] * 40 / 100);` as `ptr3[i] = (ptr1[i] * 60 + ptr2[i] * 40) / 100.0;`. I think that is way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by people in comments there are some problems in your code:

1. While computing `ptr3[i]`, since all variables in calculation expression are integer, you're getting integer as result being assigned to a double variable. You need to use a floating point number so that you get precise results:

```c
ptr3[i] = (double)(*(ptr1 + i) * 60.0 / 100);
```

2. While printing out array in `printResult()`. You are printing a double value, you should use `%f` or `%lf` instead:

```c
printf("%lf ", *(ptr3 + i));
```

When I apply these changes, I'm able to see `ptr3` array printed properly:

```
c-posts : $ gcc sum2arrays.c 
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
84.599998 52.200001 69.799999 89.200001 37.400000 47.200001 77.000000 47.799999 34.000000 57.200001
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%f` or `%lf` to print a `double` value. Printing by using `%d` will print an integer value where your array `ptr3` is of type `double`.

```c
void printResult(double* ptr3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%f ", *(ptr3 + i));
    }
}
```